# How to declare an rvalue reference to a type that undergoes template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& t);    // universal reference
template <typename T> void bar(T& t);     // lvalue reference
```

So how do we declare a strictly rvalue reference to an unknown type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to disable the function with SFINAE if `T` is deduced as an lvalue:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/942b4a044ab18045)

Or enable if `T&&` yields an rvalue reference:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/205e37a9bb27e47c)